# Why am I getting `When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act ` in one case but not another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm doing some testing with `jest` and `react-testing-library`

I've boiled this down so it's obviously not my full test.
Why does this code:

```js
test('Share renders', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<Share />)
})
```

Give me this console error: 
`When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act`

But this code:

```js
test('Share renders', async () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<Share />)
  const share = await waitForElement(() => getByText(/Share/i))

  expect(share).toBeVisible()
})
```

Does not?

My `Share` component makes a call to get some user info inside a `useEffect` hook and set it to state. This causes a rerender the first time the component is mounted. The first example then complains at me due to the state update. That makes sense. My question is, what is `waitForElement` doing that suddenly makes it NOT give me the error with the second example? Nothing has changed with the component being rendered and then immediately updating...but now the error goes away???

Comment: check if you are using React 16.9+, prior to that there [were false-positive warning](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14769#issuecomment-519732429)

Comment: Looks like 16.11 is what’s installed right now